# Load mysqli php data via ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, get, mysqli

What I'm trying to do is calling some database data via ajax and php. But the ajax call doesn't work, and I can't find out a solution on the web.

So here is my code:

test.php

```
<?php

include_once 'db_class.php';

$cat = $_GET['cat'];  

$dbconn = new dbconn('localhost', 'root', 'somepsw', 'blog');

 $dbconn->set_query("select * from posts where category = '".$cat."'");

 echo '<br/>'.$dbconn->query.'<br/>';

 $result = $dbconn->result;

 $num = $dbconn->num_results;

 $array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

 echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

If i type that url on browser: `http://127.0.0.1:82/blog/ws/test.php?cat=css`

The data returned via jsonEncode is correct, but when i'm loading it on a html page with jquery he can't read the data.

test.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function ajaxCall() {

var css;

$.ajax({                                      
      url: 'test.php',
      type: "GET",     
      data: {cat: css},              
      dataType: 'json',    
      success: function(rows)         
      {

     alert(rows);

      },
      error: function() { alert("An error occurred."); }

    });

    }

    ajaxCall();

</script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The ajax call is using '/test.php'. The browser is using '/blog/ws/test.php'. Unless you're doing some rewriting that you're not showing.

Comment: You will not get pure json data from your test.php because you have printed some echo '<br/>'.$dbconn->query.'<br/>'; remove all echo from your code except only json_encode.

Comment: Do what @ManishJangir has suggested then change `var css;` to `var css = "css";` and it will work.

Comment: You know that this is super-dangerous, right? You should never add user-input data like `GET` to an SQL statement.

Comment: Solved removing the others echo statements, and setting the var css to var= "css"; Thanks all for the support. @likeitlikeit Anyway, if that is very dangerous, how should i write the same functionality in safe way? Any advice?

Comment: The magic word is [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php). Otherwise, pretty much any SQL statement can be excuted against your DB, including DELETE and such...

Comment: @likeitlikeit thanks. I'm a designer so i don't know much about php and sql, that's my problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **variable** `css` has no value. You wanted to use the **string** `'css'`. Maybe you want to be able to load other categories, too. So change your `ajaxCall` function to

```
function ajaxCall(category)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        type: "GET",
        data: {cat: category},
        dataType: 'json',    
        success: function(rows) {
           alert(rows);
        },
        error: function() {
           alert("An error occurred.");
        }
    });
}
```

and call it using

```
ajaxCall('css');
```

Answer (score 1):

I just rewrote the php code using PDO, should be more safe now.

db.php

```
<?php

$dbhost = "localhost";  

$dbuser = "root";

$dbpsw = "somepsw";    

$dbname= "blog"; 

try {

    @$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpsw);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);  
}

catch(PDOException $e) {

    echo "Connection failed, an error occured! Please contact server administrator."; //user friendly message
    getErrorsLog($e->getMessage());
 }

 function closeDbConn () {

    $dbh = null;

 }

 function getErrorsLog($message) {

    $file = 'dberrors.log';
    $date = date("d/m : H:i :");

    // Open the file to get existing content
    $current = file_get_contents($file);
    // Append a new error message to the file
    $current .= $date.$message;
    $current .= "\r\n";
    // Write the contents back to the file
    file_put_contents($file, $current);
    exit();

 }

?>
```

blogdata.php

```
<?php

include_once "db.php";

$tableName = "posts";
$data = array();
@$view = $_GET["view"];

if (isset($_GET["view"])) { 

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE category =? ORDER BY created DESC"); 
 }
 else {  

    try {

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tableName ORDER BY created DESC");

    }

    catch (PDOException $e) {

        getErrorsLog($e->getMessage());

    }

 }

$stmt->bindValue(1, $view, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt->execute();

$affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount(); //Rows count

 if ($affected_rows == 0) {

     echo "The data you looking for no longer exist, please contact the administrator.";
     exit();
 }

foreach ($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {

    $data[] = $row;

 }

echo json_encode($data);

closeDbConn();

?>
```