# How to echo on page which is included in index file?

Tags: php, html

I have a index.php file with the following body:

```
<body>
        <!-- include navigation -->
        <header>
            <?php include 'navi.php'; ?>
        </header>   

        <!-- include content -->
        <section>
            <div>
                <?php
                if (!empty($_GET['page'])) {
                    if (!file_exists($_GET['page'] . ".php")) {
                        include("home.php");
                    } else {
                        include($_GET['page'] . ".php");
                    }
                } else {
                    include("home.php");
                }
                ?>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- include footer -->
        <?php include 'footer.html'; ?>
    </body>
```

and a nav.php:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img onclick="window.location.href = '?page=home'" id="logo" src="./images/logo.png">
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="?page=search">Search Events</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="?page=create">Create Event</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="?page=account">My Account</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="logout.php" >
                <img id="logout" src="./images/logout.png">
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

In the search page I have a simple form to search the database for a given name & type. How can I echo my results on the searchfile? If I simply `include './search.php';` the whole code from index.php is missing and unfortunately I cannot include like this: `include 'index.php?page=search';`

Comment: `include 'index.php?page=search';` - include doesn't work that way, and there was  a similar question about this a day or so ago.

Comment: Yes I know, I was just wondering if there is a function which works like this?

Comment: I doubt it. If you want, you can use JS/Ajax, that would work.

Comment: Yeah sure, how would I do it with JS/Ajax?

Comment: Have a look at this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/16637076/ and further your research using "show results from database with ajax php" for keywords. There's a lot of stuff out there. Another being http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp which many frown on W3 Schools, but it works. I've tried it before myself. That's if you're trying to fetch stuff from a db that is.

Comment: Got it working with JS/Ajax, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `include "index.php?page=search"`, you could `header("location:index.php?page=search")`, then in your index.php file, `include $_GET['page'].'php'`. Of course, you should first verify that `$_GET['page']` is actually a set variable.

Comment: I use this technique everyday. It saves one a lot of trouble.